Can I omit `ObservableObject` conformance?
Apple's documentation pretty much only says this about ObservableObject: "A type of object with a publisher that emits before the object has changed. By default an ObservableObject synthesizes an objectWillChange publisher that emits the changed value before any of its @Published properties changes.".
And this sample seems to behave the same way, with or without conformance to the protocol by Contact:
import UIKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let john = Contact(name: "John Appleseed", age: 24)
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        john.$age.sink { age in
            print("View controller's john's age is now \(age)")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        print(john.haveBirthday())
    }


}

class Contact {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var age: Int


    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }


    func haveBirthday() -> Int {
        age += 1
        return age
    }
}

Can I therefore omit conformance to ObservableObject every time I don't need the objectWillChange publisher?

You only need the ObservableObject conformance if you need a SwiftUI view to be auto-updated when an @Published property of your object changes. You also need to store the object as @ObservedObject or @StateObject to get the auto-updating behaviour and these property wrappers actually require the ObservableObject conformance.
As you're using UIKit and hence don't actually get any automatic view updates, you don't need the ObservableObject conformance.

Well, I would put it more strongly. ObservableObject is not relevant, because this is not SwiftUI. The OP should not be looking at ObservableObject at all. It doesn't apply.
